# How to extract multiple values from a record haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, syntax, extract, record

Currently, I am using list comprehension to go through a list of my custom data type

```
data Person = Person{ fname :: String
                    , lname :: String
                    , age :: Int
                    , siblings :: [String]
                    }
```

The issue is currently I am doing 
`["First name: " ++ fname z ++ "\n" ++ "Last name: " ++  lname z]` where each `z` is a `Person` from a list of `Person`.

I've tried using something like

```
fas :: [Person] -> [String]
fas listOfPerson = map fname listOfPerson
```

but how can I use map to get multiple fields from the record?
from what I understand map takes a function and a list and applies that function to every element in the list, making a new list. Because I want the output to be a single list, I only need to call `map` once, or somehow combine multiple map calls into a single list where all the information is in order?

e.g something like this?

```
fas :: [Person] -> [String]
fas listOfPerson = map (fname, lname, age) listOfPerson
```

thank you

Comment: Look up destructuring. You can bind all the record fields in the parameter list of the function using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you just need to create the right function to map with

```
renderPerson :: Person -> String
renderPerson p = "First name: " ++ fname p ++ "\nLast name: " ++ lname p
```

then map with that:

```
map renderPerson listOfPerson
```

which will give you a list of `String`s.

But maybe you wanted a list of tuples instead?

```
personTuple :: Person -> (String, String, Int)
personTuple p = (fname p, lname p, age p)
```

and use

```
map personTuple listOfPerson
```

which will give you a `[(String, String, Int)]`.  There are a variety of syntactic-sugary ways to do this, such as:

- *lambda*: `map (\p -> (fname p, lname p, age p)) listOfPerson`
- *record wildcards* (requires `RecordWildCards` extension): `personTuple Person{..} = (fname, lname, age)`
- *applicative*: `map ((,,) <$> fname <*> lname <*> age) listOfPerson`

but it's all the same in the end.